# Show animation of each item in ListView

Tags: android

I want to show fading animation on item that I remove from ListView and all items that are below it slide up to change position.
For example, I have

1

2 remove this, show fading animation

3

4

Then

1

3 slide up form last position

4 slide up form last position

I can make removed item show fading animation but I don't know how to show animation of below items.

Answer (score 0):

from user @ASH

Animate each added element in the `getView()` method of your Custom Adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
    }

    ListData o = list.get(position);
    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);

    tt.setText(o.content);

    Log.d("ListTest", "Position : "+position);
   if(flag == false) {
      Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.slide_top_to_bottom);
      v.startAnimation(animation);}
   return v;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Could you please explain more ?